# Recommended improvements on beginner Linked List

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I know this implementation is very bare-bones, but are there any improvements I can make to it? (E.g. more pythonic, style, speed, comments).

I was considering using `@property` decorators a bit more, but I thought that was overkill for this example.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return "Node Object : val {}".format(self.value)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    @property
    def length(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return 0
        length = 1
        current = self.head
        while current.next is not None:
            current = current.next
            length += 1
        return length

    def append(self, node):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = node
            return
        current = self.head
        while current.next is not None:
            current = current.next
        current.next = node

    def prepend(self, node):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = node
            return
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node

    def get(self, index):
        current = self.head
        for i in range(0, index):
            if current.next is not None:
                current = current.next
            else:
                return None
        return current

    def delete(self, val):
        if self.head.value is val:
            self.head = None
            return
        current = self.head
        while current.next is not None:
            if current.next.value is val:
                current.next = current.next.next
                return
            current = current.next
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things to consider.

### Pythonic Attributes

#### Using built-in functions

You have defined your own version of `list.length`, but Python provides a built-in function `__len__()`. So you could change:

```
@property
def length(self):
    # some code
```

to:

```
def __len__(self):
    # some code
```

Also, you could override the built-in `__str__()` function to visualize your list:

```
def __str__(self):
     nodes = []
     temp = self.head
     for i in range(self.length):
         nodes.append(str(temp.value))
         temp = temp.next
     return ' --> '.join(nodes)
```

Also, you can implement an iterator:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.iter_ref = self.head 
    self.itered = False

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.iter_ref is None and self.itered:
        self.itered = False
        raise StopIteration
    else:
        if self.iter_ref is None and not self.itered:
            self.iter_ref = self.head
            self.itered = True
        ret_val = self.iter_ref.value
        self.iter_ref = self.iter_ref.next
        return ret_val
```

Also, there is a built-in function for `get()` called `__getitem()__`. It takes, the same parameters as your function.

#### Convenience

One more thing, instead of taking in a `Node` as a parameter for your `LinkedList` functions, consider just taking in the raw data type. That means you just need to change the first two lines of the `prepend()` and `append()` to look like (for example):

```
def append(self, data):
    node = Node(data)
    # rest of the implementation
```

So now, to use your code, you can do the following:

```
ll = LinkedList()
ll.append(1)
ll.prepend(3)
print(len(ll))  # prints "2"
print(str(ll))  # prints "3 --> 1"
print(ll[0])    # prints "3"
print(list(ll)) # prints "[3, 1]"
```

### Optimizations

If you decided to take in raw data types as mentioned above, you can now perform these optimizations:

#### Computation of Length

Rather than iterate through the entire list every time you need the length, just keep the length as a member variable and increment/decrement it accordingly. Make sure to initialize `self.length = 0` in your constructor, then in your `append()` and `prepend()` methods, make sure to increment the length, and in your `delete()` method, make sure to decrement the length when you actually delete a `Node`. Then, your `__len__()` method can just look like:

```
def __len__(self):
    return self.length
```

#### Append

Also, your `append()` function could be optimized by keeping a pointer to the tail rather than iterating to the tail each time:

```
def append(self, data):
    node = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = self.tail = node
    else:
        self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node
    self.length += 1

def prepend(self, data):
    node = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = self.tail = node
    else:
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
    self.length += 1
```

Make sure to add `self.tail = None` in your constructor as well.

Here is the code that I suggested:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return "Node Object : val {}".format(self.value)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = self.tail = None
        self.length = 0
        self.iter_ref = self.head
        self.itered = False


    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __str__(self):
        nodes = []
        temp = self.head
        for i in range(self.length):
            nodes.append(str(temp.value))
            temp = temp.next
        return ' --> '.join(nodes)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.iter_ref is None and self.itered:
            self.itered = False
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            if self.iter_ref is None and not self.itered:
                self.iter_ref = self.head
                self.itered = True
            ret_val = self.iter_ref.value
            self.iter_ref = self.iter_ref.next
            return ret_val

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node
        self.length += 1

    def prepend(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            node.next = self.head
            self.head = node
        self.length += 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        current = self.head
        for i in range(index):
            if current.next is not None:
                current = current.next
            else:
                return None
        return current.value

    def delete(self, val):
        if self.head.value is val:
            self.head = None
            self.length -= 1
            return
        current = self.head
        while current.next is not None:
            if current.next.value is val:
                current.next = current.next.next
                self.length -= 1
                return
            current = current.next
```